# Проблема с методом paintEvent в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6, pyqt

Мне нужно, чтобы в окне отрисовывался ну, допустим, квадрат, но только после нажатия кнопки:

```
self.ui.buttonDraw.clicked.connect(lambda: draw.draw(self))
```

Прочитал, что нужно работать с методом paintEvent, но он почему-то запускается вместе с запуском программы, и я решил сделать так:

```
import error

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def draw(self):

    D = int(self.ui.inputBigDiameter.value())
    d1 = int(self.ui.inputTopSmallDiameter.value())
    d2 = int(self.ui.inputBottomSmallDiameter.value())
    h = int(self.ui.inputHeight.value())

    if (D != 0) and (d1 != 0 and d1 < D) and (d2 != 0 and d2 < D) and (h != 0):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)

        color = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
        color.setNamedColor("#b4b4b4")
        qp.setPen(color)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 50, 40))
        qp.drawRect(50, 50, D, h)

    else:
        error.show(self)
        qp.end()
```

С переменными всё хорошо, программа не валится, но и не рисует. Запустил дебаг и прочитал такое сообщение:

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
```

Понимаю, что нужно какое-то событие event, но не знаю как его сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: 1) Рисуйте в `paintEvent` на виджете `painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)` 2) А в `draw` сохраняйте флаг, что нужно рисовать и поля, откуда размеры возьмете (можно в классе сделать список и в него сохранять объекты, что будут рисовать в paintEvent если список не пустой) и вызывайте `self.update()`, чтобы виджет сразу же вызвал paintEvent 3) Рисование делайте в `paintEvent`. Пример рисования: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5_paintEvent_example.py#L26

Comment: я уже вам писал, что если вам действительно нужна помощь, опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, который можно воспроизвести и получить вашу проблему. А также не забывайте реагировать на ответы , которые вы получаете в ваших вопросах, почему вы этого не делаете?

Comment: Прошу прощения, коллеги. Дело в том, что проект использует базу данных и некоторые другие дополнения, из-за которых вы не сможете запустить приложение. Конечно у меня есть репозиторий на GitHub, но его минус в том, что он приватный. Ещё раз прошу прощения)